# Python 2.6 : How to pass variable to mysql query if it must be placed above application(environ?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python, python-2.6

The only way to get a variable from the URL is via
under the

```
def application(environ, start_response):
```

but the mysql code must be placed on top of this line.

what are the known options ?

> **extra info**
>
> while it may seem like it is possible to place the mysql code under
>   the
>
> ```
> def application(environ, start_response):
> ```
>
> this is not a working model because after 8 refreshes WSGI hits a 8
>   processes limits. and thus application becomes unusable.
>
> so the mysql queries must be ABOVE this line in order to not interfere
>   with WSGI's limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is sort of an answer to your earlier (deleted) question so a bit of "cheating", but you're asking the same thing I already answered there;

Your code was something like this pseudo code;

```
connection = mysql_connect()

def application(environ, start_response):
    <do some work>
    connection.close()
```

This means that you're *opening the connection once, when the file is loaded*, but once the function has run once, the connection is closed and is never opened again when the function is called again. Since the work when the function is called the second time is done on a closed connection, your WSGI will return an error. Once WSGI has gone through the 8 processes, it won't work anymore, since all processes have closed their connection.

If you instead do it like this;

```
def application(environ, start_response):   
    connection = mysql_connect()
    <do some work>
    connection.close()
```

...every call to the method will open a new connection and close it when done, and your WSGIs will happily go on working.

Comment: oh the whole database has to connect under the environ ? i was only coding the way i was coding because in PHP I would shove the mysql database connect into an external module and then do require_once(), i see. i will try this method after i fix myself up a tea.

Comment: oh by the way i don't want to be promoting tea or anything, it's usually just boiled water and sugar(powder). promoting tea might be hazardous given that it can make peoples teeth yellow.

Comment: works great, i simply moved `db=_mysql.connect("localhost","1","","1")` from the top of application(environ to the bottom of it and added 4 spaces infront. i suppose this is what PHP was doing anyway given that require_once() would have included the mysql connection and a new mysql connection would have been established, i suppose there is no such thing as "persistent mysql connection" and there can only be 1 open and 1 close for every transaction. my mind must have been confused all these years thinking php was opening it once but closing it only when needed.